# Unreal Engie 5 C++ - Error while packaging project

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I've just started to learn Unreal Engine 5 and I tried to add a C++ method into my ThirdCharacter class like this:

In the .h file:

```cpp
public:
// others public methods...
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
void PrintInRed();
```

I implemented the method in the .c file and while testing it in UE5, after compiling with Ctrl + alt + f11 everything was working. I am able to use my method in my character's blue print.

But when I want to package my game I have this kind of error message:

`[Compiler] In use pin  <Unnamed>  no longer exists on node  Call Public Func . Please refresh node or break links to remove pin. from Source: ...`

I found a way to """fix""" this issue (thanks to this page: [zenn-dev](https://zenn-dev.translate.goog/posita33/books/ue5_starter_cpp_and_bp_001/viewer/chap_03_cpp-bp-access_specifier?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=wapp&_x_tr_hist=true)) by closing UE5 and deleting the directories: Binaries, Build, DerivedDataCache, Intermediate, Saved, Script.

This solution is annoying and I was wondering if there isn't a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using blueprints at some point from the error message alone, it seems like there is still a reference to an old function you deleted some time ago inside your blueprint. Finding it, right clicking it and hitting refresh should solve this issue. The missing node should also be outlined inside the editor compiler log.